# Starting bash from /usr/bin/env or /bin

Tags: bash

Which would be advised as the first line in a bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

or

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Comment: Unless you are using bash specific features, I'd recommend `#!/bin/sh`. Otherwise, just use `#!/bin/bash`, the alternative is for interpreters which could be installed on a non-standard path.

Comment: @edwin That doesn't answer my question. Which would I then use? `#! /usr/bin/env sh` or `#! /bin/sh`? Why?

Comment: In Unix-like systems `/bin/sh` is kind of a standard... similarly for `/bin/bash`. Well, at least in most Linux distros, also notice that `#! /usr/bin/env bash` is 8 characters too many :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, using `env` is more portable. It is unlikely but theoretically conceivable to find a system that has no `bash` at `/bin/bash`. It is also possible that the user running the script has their own  bash version that is somehow different.

Using `env` means that the first `bash` instance in the user's path will be chosen. This means that `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will always work with the user's chosen bash version and it should always evaluate to an available `bash` even in non-standard systems. This becomes much more important if you are using another interpreter, not bash. Perl for example, can be installed to different locations on different systems but `env` will find it regardless.

So, using `#!/usr/bin/env PROGRAM` is a good habit to get into since it makes your scripts more portable to different *nix versions.

Comment: If `/bin/bash` doesn't exist, are we any more sure that `/usr/bin/env` will? For bash, specifically, I generally just use `/bin/bash`, because if I had to bet on one, I pick that over `/usr/bin/env`.  For almost everything else, though, I use `/usr/bin/env`

Answer (score 1):

If you have serveral versions of bash installed(possible), using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will ensure that the bash used is the first one on your environment's `$PATH`.

Using `#!/bin/bash` will be hardcoding the binary stored in `#!/bin`.

Refer: [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)