# find recursive (with ffprobe) all low quality videos (240p and 480p)

Tags: command-line, 20.04, video, ffmpeg, smartphone

How to find recursive (with `ffprobe`) all low quality videos (example 240p and 480p)? I prefer a command line solution.

Before there was iPhone and clones, I recorded already videos. They seem to have in commen to be `240p` and `480p`. I now wish to find them and manually delete most. Do you recommend other meta data than resolution for finding very old videos?

Comment: What file types are the videos? .mp4, .dv, .avi, .mkv, .mpg, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. The following script runs surprisingly fast, it process 363 files located in 138 directories for about 14 seconds.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[[ -z ${1+x} ]] && qlty="480" || qlty="$1"
[[ -z ${2+x} ]] && extn="mp4" || type="$2"
[[ -z ${3+x} ]] && baseDir="" || baseDir="${3}/"

shopt -s globstar

for file in ${baseDir}**/*${extn};
do
    ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height \
            -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$file" 2>/dev/null | \
    awk -F'x' '$2 <= q {printf "%10s\t%s\n", $0, file}' file="$file" q="$qlty"
    # For exact match of the quality change <= to ==
done
```

Copy the above script and paste it as content of an executable file that belongs to your `$PATH`, then use it as shell command. Let's assume the name of the file is `find-lq-videos.sh`, you have root privileges and `nano` is your favorite editor, so you can use the following commands to do that.

```bsh
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/find-lq-videos.sh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/find-lq-videos.sh
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/find-lq-videos.sh
```

Then go inside the parent directory where the videos are and type `find-lq-videos.sh`. By default it will search for `mp4` files with width lower or equal to `480`. Here is an example output:

```bsh
spas@desk:/mnt/Videos/Doc.and.Conspiracy$ find-lq-videos.sh
```

```
   720x400   The.Brussels.Business.2012/The.Brussels.Business (2012).mp4
   854x480   HyperNormalisation.2016/HyperNormalisation (2016).mp4
```

The script accepts three parameters. Here is how to search `mkv` <= `320`:

```bsh
spas@desk:/mnt/Videos/Doc.and.Conspiracy$ find-lq-videos.sh 320 mkv
```

```
   720x304   Inside.Job.2010/Inside.Job.2010.BG.EN.sub.mkv
```

The third parameter is the base path if it is not the current directory. Here is how to search for all files accepted by `ffprobe` within another directory:

```bsh
spas@desk:~$ find-lq-videos.sh 320 '*' /mnt/Videos/Science
```

```
   285x300   /mnt/Videos/Science/Free.Energy.The.Race.to.Zero.Point.1997.Cover.jpg
   326x240   /mnt/Videos/Science/Free.Energy.The.Race.to.Zero.Point.1997.sub.mkv
   320x240   /mnt/Videos/Science/Sugar.The.Bitter.Truth.2009.sub.mkv
```

References:

- [How do I use ffmpeg to get the video resolution?](https://superuser.com/a/841379/664884)

Comment: Thanks. The script is working, but I get this error
`./find_lowquality_vids.sh: line 9: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`

Comment: Hello, @Josefine, `shopt -s globstar` enables this fancy thing `**` which does the multilevel recursion in Bash. This is a standard option for the nowadays Bash's versions. In Bash you can find all available options and their status by the command `shopt`. So if you are primary using a shell which is not Bash, the shebang at the *first line* of the script `#!/bin/bash` become much important. In addition you could try change the shebang with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` - [reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/443747/566421).