# Having trouble understanding basic variables and commands because of my understanding of the Linux environment

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, tty, ps1

I'm having a hard time understanding some basic concepts about Linux.
And the influence of some variables on those concepts.

Those basic concepts are Virtuel environment, shell, tty.

The variabele:
$PS1 $LANG

The commands:

export (export variable from one shell to another shell ? Does this also work for tty and virtual environments ? If I open a new tab in Ubuntu (tty? terminal?) it doesn't export to the other ?

env -i ?

I think all these problems are related to my basic understanding of shells, virtual environments and tty's.

Wich is not good at the moment.

So I hope somebody will be as kind to explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome! To make a good Q&A post, You should focus your question to one topic only. Also, you can come a really long way by searching the internet for some of your questions - the answers are out there.

Comment: `tty` is not a shell but a form of communication just like telnet.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Comment: I have to flag this question, (after I upvoted), because most of your questions(you made 6), are already duplicated. You should research first in Stack all those questions, to find your answer, before asking a new question. Your question should be new (or if your problem couldn't be solved and it's specific, it should be a different question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [shell](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#1-overview) is the command line interpreter that translates commands entered by a user into actions to be performed by the operating system. The shell could be started in interactive way (where the user can type and execute commands) or in non interactive way (forked by script or program like *crontab*, etc.).

The interactive shells are started within a terminal emulator, which refers to a GUI applications as  *gnome-terminal*, *xterm*, etc., or within TTY which refers to a virtual text console. The TTYs are accessible by the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1-9</kbd>. In the desktop distributions of Linux, the desktop environment is running within one of these TTYs.

References:

- [What's the difference between the TTY and the GNOME terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/467729/566421)
- [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/201297)

No matter it is terminal emulator or TTY you are capable to do the same things with the shell running inside.

---

The default user's shell in Ubuntu is [Bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263742/what-is-bash-command-in-bash). There is an initialization file called [`.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/971846/566421) which is located in the user's home directory. This file (along with some other system initialization files as `/etc/bash.bashrc`) is [sourced](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) when the user opens a new interactive shell. Thus the user's default environment is created.

Literally by sourcing `.bashrc` some of the environment variables get certain values. Such environment variables are:

- `$PATH` which contains column separated system paths where the executable files could be found,
- `$PS1` which determines [how your prompt looks like](https://askubuntu.com/q/145618/566421), e.g.: *user@host:/current/directory$*,
- `$LANG` which sets the default locale, or `$LC_ALL` which overrides all locale settings ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/576701/what-is-the-difference-between-lang-c-and-lc-all-c) of this explanation, read more at [`man locale`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/locale.1.html)).

So if you want to permanently change some environment variable (within the user's Bash shell) you can modify (or set) its value within `.bashrc`. Otherwise, the change will only be valid for the current instance of the shell.

For example, open a new terminal and type `PS1='prompt_changed->'` and your prompt will be changed to that string. Then keep that terminal window open and open a new terminal - you will see this change is not applied there. To recover the first terminal you can source manually the `.bashrc` file by the command `. ~/.bashrc`.

---

When you use the `export` command you are exporting a variable to the [subshells](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177123/566421) that are forked from the current shell (child shells), not to the other (siblings) shells created by the parent processes of the current shell. Here is an example:

```bsh
user@host:~$ VAR='Hello!' # Define a variable called VAR
user@host:~$ echo $VAR    # Output the value of the variable
Hello!
user@host:~$ export VAR   # Export the variable
user@host:~$ bash         # Fork new bash shell
user@host:~$ echo $VAR    # Output the value of the exported variable
Hello!
user@host:~$ exit         # Exit to the parent shell
user@host:~$ sh           # Fork new sh (dash) shell
$ echo $VAR               # Output the value of the exported variable
Hello!
```

---

The command `env` is used to change the environment of a command or script execution. Here are a few lines from [`man env`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/env.1posix.html):

> `env` - set the environment for a command invocation. The  `env`  utility shall obtain the current environment,  modify
> it according to its arguments, then invoke the utility named by
> the utility operand with the modified environment.
>
> `-i` Invoke utility with exactly the environment specified by the arguments; the inherited environment shall be ignored completely.
>
> The following command: `env -i PATH=/mybin mygrep xyz myfile` invokes the command `mygrep` with a new `PATH` value as the only entry in its environment. In this case, `PATH` is used to locate `mygrep`, which then must reside in `/mybin`.

`env` is often used at the beginning of the scripts (within the so-called shebang) to increase their portability. Here are two topics that cover this usage:

- [Starting bash from /usr/bin/env or /bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443645/starting-bash-from-usr-bin-env-or-bin)
- [What type of path in shebang is more preferable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88257/what-type-of-path-in-shebang-is-more-preferable)

When run without arguments, the `env` command outputs a list of the environment variables.

---

Once again, the `.bashrc` file in the home directory customizes features of the shell, such as creating or modifying variables and aliases, and defining functions.

Fore example, let's define the following function at the bottom of the `.bashrc` file.

```bsh
hello() { echo "Hello, ${USER^}!"; }
```

After saving the file you could source it or open a new terminal instance and type `hello`.

```bsh
spas@host:~$ hello
Hello, Spas!
```

So we can see this function (or variable or alias) is available within the current shell. At this stage it is called **local** function (or variable or alias), so if we inspect the environment by `env | grep hello` our function won't be there.
Local variables exist only in the current shell, and cannot affect other commands or applications.

After defining a function (variable, alias) in `.bashrc` we can export it in order to make it available for the sub shells (commands or scripts) forked from the current shell - thus it become **global** or **environment** function (variable, alias).

```bsh
hello() { echo "Hello, ${USER^}!"; }
export -f hello
```

```bsh
spas@host:~$ source ~/.bashrc    # in bash 'source' is synopsis to '.'
spas@host:~$ env | grep 'hello'  # parse 'hello' within the output of 'env'
BASH_FUNC_hello%%=() {  echo "Hello, ${USER^}!"
```

```bsh
spas@host:~$ bash -c 'hello'     # fork an non interactive sub shell
Hello, Spas!                     # and execute the function inside
```

---

Keep in mind the non interactive shells, in most cases, doesn't source by default the initialization files as `.bashrc`, so their environment is limited than the environment of the interactive shells.

For example when you design a script that will be used by *crontab* you must use full paths to the commands or make sure it has the necessary environment.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer "I don't understand shells in tty's..." but answer "I don't understand.. ($PS1, export, env, $LANG)", then I upvoted but this question needs to be focused, there is already an answer for tty's here in Stack.

Comment: He made 6 different questions: 1.  What's PS1 purpose (there is a lot of technical details actually about this topic) 2. starting a second virtual shell in the same tty? 3. I can export variables to other shells within the first shell 4. You can use the env command to set the $LANG... 5. What does env -i actually do? 6.basic understanding of shells and tty's